# How to extract UTC offset from given date

Tags: node.js, date, dayjs

I use **Dayjs** library for date parsing/manipulation in nodejs.
Consider a date = "2023-07-21T12:00:00+05:00".
When I try to get utcOffset by using dayjs(date).utcOffset() it returns "**60**" in minutes, although offset in minutes of given date is "**300**".

I think it coverts the date into local-timezone where server is hosted and returns that utcOffset.
But I want to extract offset from the given date like in this case "**+05:00**" or "**300**" in minutes. I tried string split method but that is not good as date format may change.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "where server is hosted" - if this is the reason, run it on your local PC as server and see the difference.

Comment: the difference is "+01:00", I think it's in Europe

Answer (score 0):

While the timezone offset in your string is taken into account when parsing the string

JS dates don't contain a timezone.

The timezone is global for all dates and it's of the current environment.

> date.getTimezoneOffset() returns the difference, in minutes, between date as evaluated in the UTC time zone and as evaluated in the local time zone — that is, the time zone of the host system in which the browser is being used (if the code is run from the Web in a browser), or otherwise the host system of whatever JavaScript runtime (for example, a Node.js environment) the code is executed in.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

Comment: Hmm, seems there's no way of preserving offset in the given date string.

Comment: @FarrukhAhmad exactly